# How can I use a cell array as axis ticks in a pcolor plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot a heat map using `pcolor` which is working fine, but both the x-axis ticks are just increasing integers labelling each data point.

Is there a way I can plot so that one of the axes uses a cell array as its ticks?

For example, at the moment I have data like:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
z = [4, 2, 6; 5, 3, 1; 6, 4, 5]
```

Then `pcolor(x,y,z)` would throw an error saying the data inputs must be real.

`pcolor(z)` would work, but tick both axes `1 2 3`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x`, `y` and `z` are supposed to contain your data, not the tick labels. You can change the tick labels of any plot by setting the `XTickLabel` and/or `YTickLabel` property of the axes:

```
x = 1:3;
y = 1:3;
z = rand(3);
pcolor(x,y,z);
set(gca,'XTick',1:3);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'a','b','c'});
```

Result:

[image: Plot result]